# Problem with multiple GCC compilers (FPC and MSYS2)

Tags: c, gcc, freepascal, msys2

I have a Windows 11 machine with GCC installed using Msys2, which I use to compile C files from my university which always worked flawlessly. The problem is that we have a new course at our university that asks us to use Pascal as a demostration of some programming theory concepts. I decided to install FPC using the Windows installer. After that I compiled the Pascal file no problem. But later I tried to compile C files and got the following error:

gcc.exe: installation problem, cannot exec `cc1': No such file or directory

I found that FPC has a GCC of it's own in it's files, and I know path and system enviorment variables are an issue in Windows, I removed FPC from the variable list, and that obviously broke FPC but the GCC command started working again. So I deduce that the two GCC files cannot coexist in the Enviorment Variables.

It's a pain having to manipulate the System Variables everytime I have to use one or the other, and I'm screwed if I have to use both at the same time. So the question is:

Is there a way for both of these GCC.exe to coexist, maybe selecting which one I want to use?? Or make FPC work with the other GCC, so I can erase the GCC that comes with FPC?? Or am I completely wrong and there is another problem?? XD I really don't know at this point.

Comment: One workaround would be to have two batch files to set the path differently depending on what you want to use. You could make two shortcuts for different command prompts too if you wanted.

Comment: MSYS2 has a shortcut that opens Bash with PATH override, pointing to its GCC and other utilities. You could remove it from system-wide path and use it from this shell.

Answer (score 1):

Free Pascal has own (pre msys mingw) copies of some binaries. Mostly from binutils , findutils, make etc to operate a minimal buildsystem.

One of those is windres, the resource compiler, which uses GCC for preprocessing. The FPC "gcc" is a dummy file that just implements the minimal header preprocessing that windres requires. It is not a compiler.

Note that mixing makes is also quite often a problem, so the only sane way is not to have them in the PATH at the same time.

I use this batchfile to enable FPC in the path, I have a similar one for cygwin.

```
@echo off

Rem we save oldpath only once, so we can always revert to it.

if "%OLDPATH%" neq "" goto :nosave
set OLDPATH=%PATH%
:nosave 
SET PATH=%OLDPATH%
rem preprend the relevant path, since I also have Delphi in the path that also comes with a MAKE
PATH c:\pp32\bin\i386-win32;%PATH%
```

Calling multiple such batchfile in quick succession only swaps the relevant directory, and doesn't make the PATH increasingly longer with duplicates.